# How to get the modified object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a requirement where I need to send modified value alone in the object.

Following is my object:

```
{
     "Code": 200,
     "ErrorMessage": null,
     "Result": {
         "Locations": [{
             "LocationName": "Location 1",
             "Address": "XYZ",
             "City": "Houston",
             "State": "TEXAS",
             "StateCode": "TX",
             "Zipcode": "75201"
         },
         {
             "LocationName": "Location 2",
             "Address": "ABC",
             "City": "Germantown",
             "State": "CALIFORNIA",
             "StateCode": "CA",
             "Zipcode": "90001"
         }]
     }
}
```

I used ng-repeat inorder to display data which has input fields. Now If I modify Location 1 in that Locations Object. I want to send only Location 1 details.

Is it possible to do that in Angular. I am new to angular.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please [edit] your question and show us what you tried. Thank you

Comment: I didn't tried anything. I don't know the way first to proceed

Comment: If you're in ng repeat, then you can pass the object to the controller,  like this: `<div ng-repeat="location in data.Result.Locations"> <button ng-click="save(location)"></button> </div>` - This is the first step to proceed

Comment: Done. Its working. Thanks Alon

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ng-change` to get the modified object

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.changeItem = function(item){
  console.log(item.LocationName)
}

$scope.items = {
     "Code": 200,
     "ErrorMessage": null,
     "Result": {
         "Locations": [{
             "LocationName": "Location 1",
             "Address": "XYZ",
             "City": "Houston",
             "State": "TEXAS",
             "StateCode": "TX",
             "Zipcode": "75201"
         },
         {
             "LocationName": "Location 2",
             "Address": "ABC",
             "City": "Germantown",
             "State": "CALIFORNIA",
             "StateCode": "CA",
             "Zipcode": "90001"
         }]
     }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-repeat="item in items.Result.Locations">
    <input ng-model="item.LocationName" ng-change="changeItem(item)"/>
 </div>
</div>
```